# Display text link to open specific PDF page from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, excel-2003

I found a VBA code online that opens up an internal (shared drive) PDF document page in IE (e.g. goes to page 8 of PDF file). I would like to display text in the cell for a user to click (e.g. "Click here to view").

**Problem**: The cell currently displays '0' and I have to go to the function bar and hit [Enter] to execute.

**Excel Version**: 2003

**Function call**:

```
=GoToPDFpage("S:\...x_2011.pdf",8)
```

**VBA Code**:

```
Function GoToPDFpage(Fname As String, pg As Integer)
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With IE
.Navigate Fname & "#page=" & pg
.Visible = True
End With
End Function
```

:EDIT:

I was able to display text, but it's still not a link like I wanted.

```
="Click to view" & GoToPDFpage("S:\...x_2011.pdf",8)
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi Fiona, it might be an easier way to solve your needs.  Is it possible for you to have your filenames and page numbers in separate columns for each row?  The idea is to have a "Click here to view" button and in the column besides it the file name and in the next column the page number.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont have a high complex workbook/worksheet you could try the following:

Turn the "Click to view" cell into a Hyperlink with following characteristics.

- Make it point to itself
- The text inside the cell must always be the string ***Page=*** plus the number that you what the pdf to open in. Eg.: ***Page=8***

Then go to the workseet module and paste the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)

    If Left(ActiveCell.Value, 4) = "Page" Then

        GoToPDFpage Range("A1").Value, Mid(ActiveCell.Value, 6)
        'This code asumes that the file address is writen in the cell A1

    End If
    '
End Sub
'
```

The above written code will trigger every time you run a hyperlink in the worksheet.
As the hyperlink always point to itself, the "Activecell.Value" will always have the page number that you want to open.

I'm assuming that you can put the file address in the cell A1.  You could modify this portion to point to any other cell. (including: The cell to the right of the current hyperlink, etc).

This might not be the best option, but if you only need a quick feature in a couple of cells, it might be enough.

Hope it helps !

---

**EDIT:**
To make each HLink reference to itself, you can select all the cells where you have the links and then run this procedure:

```
Sub RefHLink()
    Dim xCell As Range

    For Each xCell In Selection

        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=xCell, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
        xCell.Address, ScreenTip:="Click Here", TextToDisplay:="Page="
    Next xCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you.  I will try this.  I actually have a column of < 60 rows that each need a "hyperlink" to different PDF pages.

Comment: Then you could put the pdf file path at the right of each the cell and then change this line: "Range("A1").Value" with the following line: "Activecell.Offset(0,1).Value".

Comment: Sorry, finally had time to take a look at this.  I tried this: =HYPERLINK(GoToPDFpage("S:\HP\HP Analyst\Kori\EOC\2011\kpif_20d_Rx_POP3_2011.pdf",8), "Click to view EOC")... which seems to work except it opens the file twice.  I did not insert the code you suggested above -- just my original code.  Almost there!!  Thanks!

Comment: I tried inserting your code, but couldn't figure out how to make the hyperlink reference itself.

Comment: I edited the post so you have a procedure to reference the Hyperlinks.

Answer (score 1):

how about letting excel write a batch file then running it?

*edit paths to pdf and AcroRd32.exe

```
Sub batfile()
  Dim retVal
  filePath = "path\pdf.bat"
  pg = 2
  Open filePath For Output As #1
  Print #1, "Start /Max /w " & Chr(34) & "Current E-book" & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" & Chr(34) & " /a " & Chr(34) & "page=" & pg & Chr(34) & "  " & Chr(34) & "H:\Documents\RPG\Dragonlance\New folder\Sample File.pdf" & Chr(34) & ""
  Close #1
  retVal = Shell(strFilePath)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Menu->Data->Data Validation.  In the 2nd tab you can write your message.

Comment: Thank you for your input.  Your suggestion creates a popup field.  I was looking to see if I can put a text link in the cell that says "Click to View".  When the user clicks it, Excel will run the function above and open the PDF page.

Comment: Ok, I was able to display text, but it's not a link.  ="Click to view" & GoToPDFpage("S:\...x_2011.pdf",8)  Want to be able to click on that text to trigger the GoToPDFpage function.  Thanks.